# JAVA - Método Sillas

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de implementar un método de nombre:
*hayNumSillasEconomicasLibresPasilloVentana()*

La cosa va así:

En la clase avión hay sillas económicas (42) y sillas ejecutivas (8). El método recibe, como parámetro, un entero llamado *nSillas*. El método debe indicar si hay por lo menos un cierto número de sillas económicas (ese número es el parámetro) libres y ubicadas **en el pasillo o en la ventana**. El avión está dividido en pasillo, ventana y central. Todos los métodos y atributos están especificados en el diagrama UML adjunto.

[image: Diagrama UML adjunto]

Ya están definidos los métodos *contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasPasillo*, que retorna el número de sillas económicas libres que están ubicadas en el pasillo, y *contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasVentana*, que retorna el número de sillas económicas libres que están ubicadas en la ventana.

Mi intento:

```
public boolean hayNumSillasEconomicasLibresPasilloVentana(int nSillas)
{
int sillasEconomicasDesocupadasVentana =    
contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasVentana();    
int sillasEconomicasDesocupadasPasillo =   
contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasPasillo();    
boolean encontrado = false;

if (sillasEconomicasDesocupadasVentana == nSillas ||  
sillasEconomicasDesocupadasPasillo == nSillas)    
{
encontrado = true;
}
return encontrado;
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antebrazo

Comment: Me parece que es un problema de logica.. si hay 8 sillas libres, pero hay 4 en pasillo y 4 en ventana, entonces siempre vas a devolver false... en realiada buscas algo asi como sillaspasillo + sillasventana >= sillasquebuscas ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que debes hacer es sumar el numero de sillas economicas desocupadas en  el pasillo y la ventana y compararlo con nSillas

```
public boolean hayNumSillasEconomicasLibresPasilloVentana(int nSillas){
    if(contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasVentana() + contarSillasEconomicasDesocupadasPasillo()>= nSillas){
       return true;
    }
    return false,
}
```